# Modern VJ Software

Tags: software-recommendation, macos

I've been playing around with [GrandVJ](http://www.arkaos.net/product/index.php?catid=1&pid=1001&iid=42) and it's reasonably compelling software. My initial problem is that it's corrupted my video output twice already in the first few days of using it, requiring a restart each time.

I'm looking for a piece of software that is well-integrated into the OS X environment, supports Quartz Composer (.qtz) files, and has support for external controllers such as the [NuVJ](http://nuvj.arkaos.net/nuvj/) or a [supported Ableton Live controller](http://www.ableton.com/controllers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [VDMX](http://vidvox.net/) a try.

See [this thread](http://vidvox.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=2188) for info on using the NuVJ (and other MIDI controllers).

Comment: VDMX was quite overwhelming at first, but I was attracted by a couple of the pre-fab visualizations. I suspect it will be much better after I obtain a controller :).

Thanks for the recommendation.